# Masonry on Wordpress overlapping other content

Tags: jquery, wordpress, masonry

I have a client with a WP install and Genesis theme.
I am using masonry to tile posts on a specific category.
The problem I am having is that there is other content on the page that the masonry overlaps (category description).
I have tried $window.on('load', function(){

and I have tried setting a timeout to delay the masonry.

No matter what I do, when masonry initializes, the posts cover the description content.
Any suggestions?
Thanks in advance.

EDIT: masonry code in use ->

```
jQuery(window).on('load',function($) {
var $container = jQuery('#content');
// initialize
$container.imagesLoaded( function() {
$container.masonry({
columnWidth: 1,
itemSelector: '.post'
});
});
});
```

Live link on site: http://landmark2skate.com/category/secret-stash/

Thanks for taking a look.

Comment: Can you post your code and/or a link to your live site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is more of a css issue

[ Text ] - Your text block is 1 single element

[ Masonry ] - your boxes covering your text is many individual divs with the style of **position:absolute**

Without a parent div that contains these individual item divs your masonry will positioned 
absolute to the first parent position relative container you have.

Comment: Thanks, looks like I have to write a custom loop to take care of it.

Comment: what you need is a containing div <div style=pos:relative> <masonry> <masonry> <masonry></div>  ------- right now your web looks like this  <div style=pos:relative> <text> <masonry> <masonry> <masonry></div>

Comment: Exactly what Im going for. I might be able to pull it off with a hook in Genesis so I dont have to rewrite the whole loop and jack all the css.

Answer (score 0):

You've got your 'columnWidth' set to '1'. That means 1 pixel. Try setting it to a larger amount like 250.

See the example here:

http://masonry.desandro.com/options.html

Comment: actually, I should have it unset, because I want it to take the hint from the first element (1 has worked for me also).